# Wicket page links do not use mounted URL coding strategy?

Tags: url, hyperlink, wicket

In the Wicket Application class I have mounted a page at the location /about

```
mountBookmarkablePage("about", AboutPage.class);
```

I verify that the about page is available at /about. Then in the page which needs a link to the about page, I use the Wicket Link class:

```
add(new Link("link") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(AboutPage.class);
            }

        };
)
```

The links work as expected but the target URL diplayed in the browser status bar when the mouse is over the link looks like

```
http://localhost:8080/?wicket:interface=:0:linkpage:repeating:1:link::ILinkListener::
```

A workaround which I have found is to use ExternalLink

```
new ExternalLink("link", "/about", "about");
```

This changes the target URL to

```
http://localhost:8080/about
```

which is displayed in the browser status bar when the mouse is over the link.

Is there a way to use the mounted URL as the target link with Wicket Link class, or is there a way to get the mount location for a class, so that I can use it to build the link url for AboutPage.class (instead of hard coding it in the ExternalLink constructor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose you should use [BookmarkablePageLink](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html) *(as you're saying you're doing)*, to set the link label *(or any other content for that matter)* just call `.add(Component... c)` since BookmarkablePageLink is actually a [MarkupContainer](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html).

So, to create a link to `AboutPage.class` you need to do this:

```
BookmarkablePageLink aboutLink = new BookmarkablePageLink("link", AboutPage.class);
aboutLink.add(new Label("linkText", "Go to About page"));
add(aboutLink);
```

and the matching markup

```
<a wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="linkText">Link text goes here</span></a>
```

Yeppers, it's slightly more verbose but also very easily extensible. If you want to, you can create your own convenience subclass of `BookmarkablePageLink` called `BookmarkableTextLink` and have a

```
new BookmarkableTextLink(String id, Class<Page> pageClass, String linkText);
```

constructor for it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: the BookmarkablePageLink class

```
add(new BookmarkablePageLink("link", AboutPage.class));
```

This solution only has a small problem: the link label can not be set, maybe this can be done by assigning a model.